# In a List of user defined Class how to add unique entry. i.e. if the Reg.No is unique then it will add in the listofStudents

Tags: c#, list

```
    //define new List for Students
    List<Student> listofStudents = new List<Student>();
    private Student student;
    //Save Button
    private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        student = new Student();
        student.regNo = regNoTextBox.Text;
        student.firstName = firstNameTextBox.Text;
        student.lastName = lastNameTextBox.Text;
        student.GetFullName();
        listofStudents.Add(student);
        regNoTextBox.Text = "";
        firstNameTextBox.Text = "";
        lastNameTextBox.Text = "";
    }
```

here i want if the regNo is unique then listofStudents will add the student

Comment: Could you show us what have you tried and didn't work?

Comment: @ramzab ali did you solve your problem ?

Comment: I suspect you are asking how to dedupe a list, or how to avoid adding duplicates in a list. You should probably try to rephrase the question.

Comment: @vivek nuna, yes I have solved the problem according to your solution. And sorry for late in response.

Comment: @ Martin Algesten, you are right. I want to  avoid adding duplicates in a list. And it's my shortcoming for not making the question clear. Thanks for your correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your requirement is, If list does not have a student with a given registration id then you want to add this student to list?

You can use `Any` to find whether list has an item or not.

```
if (listofStudents.Any(item => item.regNo == student.regNo) == false)
    {
        listofStudents.Add(student);
    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot @vivek nuna. Your code just awesome.  I am looking for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some counter that will increase by 1 after each adding to list:

```
private int Counter { get; set; }
```

Then you add students like below:

```
Student student = new Student()
{
    regNo = Counter++,
    firstName = "John",
    lastName = "Doe"
};
listofStudents.Add(student);
```

Answer (score 0):

building on @viveknuna solution, I'd propose the following:

add proper constructor to your `Student` class:

```
public class Student
{
    public string regNo { get; set; }
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }

    public Student(string regno, string firstname, string lastname)
    {
        regNo = regno;
        firstName = firstname;
        lastName = lastname;
    }
}
```

then your code becomes:

```
List<Student> listofStudents = new List<Student>();

private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!listofStudents.Any(item => item.regNo == regNoTextBox.Text))
    {
        listofStudents.Add(new Student(firstNameTextBox.Text, lastNameTextBox.Text, regNoTextBox.Text));
        student.GetFullName();
    }
    regNoTextBox.Text = "";
    firstNameTextBox.Text = "";
    lastNameTextBox.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable feedback @user3598756. I have learned a great new thing from you. :)